# Battleship stuck on battle board implementation

Tags: java, oop

we recently somewhat learned Object Oriented Programming and already have a project on it due soon, so I am not too familiar with OOP. However, we were assigned a project of creating a Battleship game.

I have created a ship, square, and battle board class. I have tested all three, and all tests have also passed except for one method on Battleboard classs. To test each class, I used a toString method. This is in my battle board's toString method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `square` is assigned `new Square()` **after** loop iteration? And what value does it have before the first iteration? Also, what is in `ship` variable?

Comment: square and ship are private instances = null;
Ship returns its length, # of times hit, start col/row (upper left corner) and orientation. Square knows if it has a ship and if it has been hit.

Comment: I doubt that `ship` is `null`, otherwise this `ship.getLength()` would throw an exception; instead it appends `"1 "` to output. Anyway, the code is incomplete; could you please show all the relevant code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of problems that I spotted, there can be more as the code is still incomplete:

A. In the very beginning of

```
public boolean addShip(int length, boolean isHorizontal, int startRow, int startCol) {
```

there is

```
square = new Square();
```

It seems logical to check whether a ship exists at the square to which you add it, but instead you check whether it exists in a brand new square. We don't have `Square` code, but I assume that it does not have a ship initially.

B. In the same method there is the following code:

```
    if (isHorizontal == true) {
        ship = new Ship(length, isHorizontal, startRow, startCol);
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.getLength(); i++) {
            if (startCol > numberOfColumns) {
                return false;
            } else {
                square.addShip(ship);
                startCol++;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the ship is being repeatedly added to the same brand new square which is not related to the board. Later, that square is not added anywhere and now used anyhow.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but probably *all the squares should have been inialized before this method is called, no squares should been created in this method; instead, you need to find a square corresponding to the current iteration`*.

C. The following code

```
        } else if (!square.hasBeenHit() && square.hasShip()) { 
        //Returns length of ship if there is a ship that hasn't been hit
            if (ship.getLength() == 1) {
                toString += "1 ";
            } else if (ship.getLength() == 2) {
                toString += "2 ";
            } else if (ship.getLength() == 3) {
                toString += "3 ";
            } else if (ship.getLength() == 4) {
                toString += "4 ";
            }
        }
```

uses the same `ship` on all iterations, so it behaves in the same way on all the iterations (appends `1`). *The correct thing would be to find a ship belonging to the current square (i, j), if it exists, and use it*.

D. A brand new square is created on each loop, again, although you are iterating over squares! *It would be more logical to write `square = squares[i][j]` instead of `square = new Square()`*.

I'd recommend you to use a debugger to see what happens in your code.

Comment: I am confused what you mean by C. Wouldn't the for loop take care of the square location? 
Also in D I get a nullPointerException if I add square = squares[I][j]

Comment: On C. `square = new Square();` creates a brand new object which does not know anything about the current iteration, `i` and `j`. On C: probably `squares` array is not initialized anyhow. I would recommend to init all the squares on the board when you create your board.

Comment: I erased all `square = new Square();` and added squares[I][j] = new Square(); to init them but output is still "1 1 1 1" as opposed to "- - - -" or "2 - - -" as opposed to "2 2 - -"

Comment: Is there a way to contact you outside of this website? Or can you notify me if you get this notification?